# Which degree sequences are planar graphical?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

The [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) characterizes which degree sequences are graphical (i.e. realizable by a simple graph).

There has been some work on which degree sequences are planar graphical (i.e. realizable by a simple planar graph).  See, for example, [On Planar Graphical Degree Sequences by Schmeichel and Hakimi](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2100346) (1977).

What is currently known about which degree sequences are planar graphical?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is always difficult to say what is "currently known," but at least around
2008, the paper

> "A Characterization of the degree sequences of 2-trees."
>   Prosenjit Bose, Vida Dujmovi, Danny Krizanc, Stefan Langerman, Pat Morin, David R. Wood, Stefanie Wuhrer.
>   *Journal of Graph Theory*
>   Volume 58, Issue 3, pages 191–209, July 2008.
>   ([journal link)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.20302/abstract)

gives a pretty definitive summary of the state of the art:

> That a sequence of $n$ positive integers is the degree sequence of a tree if and only
>   if it sums to $2n − 2$ is a folklore result. Other graph
>   families with known degree sequence characterizations
>   include split graphs `[14, 20]`, $C_4$-minor free graphs `[21]`,
>   unicyclic graphs `[1]`, cacti graphs `[15]`, Halin graphs `[2]`,
>   and edge-maximal outerplanar graphs `[18]`. The most
>   investigated class of graphs is that of planar graphs.
>   Despite the eﬀort, no characterization of the degree
>   sequences of planar graphs is known, even for edge-maximal planar graphs. 
>   Partial results are obtained in
>   `[5, 13, 11, 16]`.

And, obviously, that paper characterizes [2-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree).