# Is there a Havel-Hakimi for geometric graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, discrete-geometry, degree-sequence

Suppose that we are given $n$ points in the plane, with a degree prescribed for each, and the question is whether we can place a [geometric graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory) on them. Is there an efficient algorithm for this?

Note that this is *not* the same as [Erdős–Gallai for planar graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119887/which-degree-sequences-are-planar-graphical).
My motivation is to solve a puzzle game on my phone :P

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which puzzle game? :)

Comment: @Shamisen Windows Phone/Logic Games app/Neighbours puzzle.

Comment: Your link describes different type of geometric graphs. Do you mean plane graph with straight edges?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, planar straight line graph.